# iOS UIText fields stop responding to key press events. Why?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, keypress

I can get my app into a state where the UITextField controls stop responding to key presses.

I still have a blinking insertion caret. The keyboard has appeared. UITextField delegate methods are being properly called.

The only thing is that the key press events don't work. It seems to happen after I've called the following UIViewController method:

```
- (void)transitionFromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromViewController
                    toViewController:(UIViewController *)toViewController 
                            duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration 
                             options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options 
                          animations:(void (^)(void))animations 
                          completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion;
```

Any ideas what could be causing this? How to prevent or fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On completion of the transition, try

```
[yourTextField becomeFirstResponder]
```

Answer (score 0):

The code had already been calling becomeFirstResponder where needed which is why the keyboard was coming up and there was a blinking insertion caret.

But there is one more thing you need for your app to accept key presses. Your application window has to be the key window.

Turns out it was caused by the use of a window that comes to the foreground during network operations that has a wait indicator on it.

That window was becoming the key window.

The main app window was not being assigned to be the key window when the wait indicator window was dismissed.

So, in my application delegate, I added the following line:

```
[waitIndicatorWindow resignKeyWindow];
[waitIndicatorWindow removeFromSuperview];
waitIndicatorWindow = nil;

[self.window makeKeyWindow]; <- added this line to fix the problem.
```